# conditional in_array trouble with PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, if-statement

I have firePHP so i know exactly what the variables are, but I can't figure out why this code doesn't change it.

I receive from a mySQL call $query (which if returned produces `[{"type":"2"}]`)
I have 4 potential types, and things can be multiple types (i.e. `[{"type":"1"},{"type":"2"}]`)

Now I want to read this data and run various other functions based on the type it has, that is: if it's only type 2, call function TWO, if it's type 1 and 2 call function ONE and function TWO. I thought this would be easiest if i moved all the data into another array.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
$result = array('message'=>false, 'money'=>false, 'glasses'=>false, 'exclamation'=>false);
    if (in_array('1',$query)) {$result['message'] = true;}
    if (in_array('2',$query)) {$result['money'] = true;}
    if (in_array('3',$query)) {$result['glasses']=true;}
    if (in_array('4',$query)) {$result['exclamation']=true;}
    echo json_encode($result);
```

This however does not update the $result array (as I can tell all of the values of `$message` are `false` in firePHP.... Thus I assume something is wrong with my if statements, but what?

Comment: Can you please put the complete output of $query, using print_r for instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure about the value of `$query`, but if it is something like:

```
array [0 => '{"type":"2"}']
```

You would have to use:

```
in_array('{"type":"2"}',$query)
```

as that is the value of your variable.

Comment: Oh, wow I knew it was going to be something simple...I had tried in_array('2', $query[0]) but that gave an error, why is that different?

Comment: @mazlix It's different because 2 is only a part of the value held in `array(0 => '{"type":"2"}')` The only way your code would have worked would have been if the array looked like this `array(0 => 2)`

Comment: @mazlix Your value is not an array in php, it is a string. It´s the object notation for javascript, but php only sees a string.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the results returned in $query are arrays of arrays, and thus in_array is only searching at the top level and not sub-levels? It seems like what you want is to recursively search $query.